# Scala: curried constructors

Tags: scala, constructor, currying

I have the following Scala class:

```
class Person(var name : String, var age : Int, var email : String)
```

I would like to use the Person constructor as a curried function:

```
def mkPerson = (n : String) => (a : Int) => (e : String) => new Person(n,a,e)
```

This works, but is there another way to accomplish this? This approach seems a bit tedious and error-prone. I could imagine something like Function.curried, but then for constructors.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This will work:

```
def mkPerson = (new Person(_, _, _)).curried
```

Comment: Just a quick note, if you're sure to call it may as well make it `val mkPerson = ...`. Also, if Person were a case class you could simply use `(Person.apply _).curried`

Answer (score 11):

A bit late to this party, but if you make `Person` a case class:

```
scala> case class Person(name: String, age: Int, email: String)
defined class Person
```

Scala generates a companion object containing `Person.apply(String, Int, String)` and some other stuff for you. Then you can do:

```
scala> Person.curried
res5: String => (Int => (String => Person)) = <function1>
```

Which is shorthand for:

```
(Person.apply _).curried
```

It works with var parameters too.

Answer (score 8):

may be so:

```
val mkPerson = Function.curried((n: String,a:Int,e:String) => new Person (n,a,e))
```

Comment: I see. It's still more complex than I'd hoped for: I was thinking of something more along the lines of Haskell constructors.